# Feature request: NumPy Reader

Tags: numpy, cntk

I have a large collection of NumPy arrays saved on disk. I would like to read them efficiently and concurrently with the training. I can't load them all into memory at once - the data set is too large.
Additionally, it would be nice to apply some user defined transforms on the fly. Also it would be nice to be able to read them from C++, not just Python.

I believe CNTK does not have this capability now, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we don't have build-in numpy reader. However, you have multiple options:

1. Read the numpy data in batches and feed them to the trainer, here an example that read images into numpy array and feed it to the trainer: 
   https://github.com/Microsoft/FERPlus
2. What the data inside your numpy array? Can you convert it to a format readable by one of the CNTK readers?